# Fetch the record where a column value only exist in a particular group in Postgresql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

my Postgresql TABLE looks like,

```
CREATE TABLE foo(man_id, subgroup, power, grp)
AS VALUES
    (1, 'Sub_A',  4, 'Group_A'),
    (2, 'Sub_B', -1, 'Group_A'),
    (3, 'Sub_A',  5, 'Group_A'),
    (4, 'Sub_B',  1, 'Group_A'),
    (5, 'Sub_B',  6, 'Group_B'),
    (6, 'Sub_B',  2, 'Group_B'),
    (7, 'Sub_C',  2, 'Group_B');
    (8, 'Sub_B',  2, 'Group_C');
```

We have four columns `man_id`, `subgroup`, `power`, `grp`. I want to fetch the records where a `subgroup` is only exist in one `grp` . Here, you can find `Sub_A subgroup` only in `Group_A grp`. So, my expected result should be,

```
1, Sub_A,  4, Group_A
3, Sub_A,  5, Group_A
```

What is the recommended way to achieve it ?

MySQL solution will be expected too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `not exists`:

```
select f.*
from foo f
where not exists (select 1
                  from foo f2
                  where f2.subgroup = f.subgroup and
                        f2.grp <> f.grp
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `GROUP BY` clause if, you want only subgroup & it's group :

```
select subgroup, max(grp) as grp
from foo f
group by subgroup
having min(grp) = max(grp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query will produce the desired result.

```
 with foo(man_id, subgroup, power, grp) as (
    select * from
    (
    VALUES
    (1, 'Sub_A',  4, 'Group_A'),
    (2, 'Sub_B', -1, 'Group_A'),
    (3, 'Sub_A',  5, 'Group_A'),
    (4, 'Sub_B',  1, 'Group_A'),
    (5, 'Sub_B',  6, 'Group_B'),
    (6, 'Sub_B',  2, 'Group_B'),
    (7, 'Sub_C',  2, 'Group_B'),
    (8, 'Sub_B',  2, 'Group_C')
    ) as x(man_id, subgroup, power, grp)
),res (subgroup) as (
   select
     subgroup
   from foo
   group by subgroup
   having count(distinct grp)=1
)
select f.* from foo f join res using(subgroup)
```